# angularjs $watch is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have written this code to watch changes in password field,
My code is

```
var Controllers = angular.module('myapp');
  Controllers.controller('SignUpCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location) {

    $scope.$watch($scope.password, validatePasswordFun);

            function validatePasswordFun(newValue,oldValue,scope){
                    console.debug("Test");
        }
});
```

But problem that i am facing is : 
on page load, it prints "test" in firebug console,

After that if i enter text/password in password field, it does not execute the function.

Comment: I think you do not use ng-model in your HTML

Comment: @SET Thanks, i was using ng-model="user.password" not just "password"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are watching in wrong way it should be string value like

```
var Controllers = angular.module('myapp');
  Controllers.controller('SignUpCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location) {

    $scope.$watch('password', validatePasswordFun);

            function validatePasswordFun(newValue,oldValue,scope){
                    console.debug("Test");
        }
});
```

Internally watch is using $parse service available which expects the property name so you wrap inside a string 'password' so that $parse could work properly

--edit working html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Demo" >

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-controller="test" >
        <input type="password" ng-model="password" />
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('Demo', []);
            function test($scope) {
                $scope.$watch('password', function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
                    alert(newvalue);
                });
            }
        </script>
  </body>



</html>
```

Comment: i have added the html pls see sample demo

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Actually i was using ng-model="user.password" and not "password". Now i changed my $watch to $scope.$watch('user.password', validatePasswordFun); and its working now.

Comment: I ran into this too. For some reason I had to use an object rather than a simple scope var in order for watch to work. Had to change from $scope.$watch('searchText', function (term) to $scope.$watch('searchText.value', function (term)